# How can I install Dragon Player on NixOS?

Tags: nixos

I've found it [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/kde/srcs.nix), but I have no clue how to install it. Are KDE packages handled differently from regular packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe only the tarball fetcher is there but not the actual package.  See https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/desktops/plasma-5/default.nix#L13 – so it's up to you ;-)